# How to create good Conversation and User relation in Prisma

Tags: postgresql, prisma

This is my model so far

```
model Conversation{
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  participants User[]
  messages Message[]

  @@map("conversations")

}
```

And this is how I wanted to create one in database with NestJS:

```
  const sender: User = await this.prisma.user.findFirst({
    where: {
      id: userId,
    },
  });

  const receiver: User = await this.prisma.user.findFirst({
    where: {
      id: receiverId,
    },
  });

  conversation = await this.prisma.conversation.create({
    data: {
      participants: [sender, receiver],
    },
  });
```

The problem with this is that Nest is not letting me do so because it says that the types on 'participants' is not valid even though I am literally giving it array of Users that I specified in model.